# How to force 32bit app to use a 64bit COM dll in CreateObject?

Tags: sql-server, com, 32bit-64bit, createobject

The following code behaves differently depending on if I use the 32 or 64 bit version of wscript:

```
Set oSQLServer = CreateObject("SQLDMO.SQLServer")

For Each o in oSQLServer.ListInstalledInstances
    MsgBox o
Next
```

In 32 bit, it will list the instances of my 32bit server (SQL Server 2000), in 64 bit I get the contents of my 64bit server (SQL Server 2008).
I need to convert this code to C++ (a 32 bit application).  But I need to show the 64bit servers.  How do I force the created object to use the 64bit dll and 64bit key in the registry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to use ODBC's SQLBrowseConnect with the connection string

```
"DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};".
```

SQLDMO is well and truely dead, and SQLSMO is rather short-sightedly for managed applications only.

Answer (score 5):

A 32-bit app cannot load a 64-bit DLL, and a 64-bit app cannot load a 32-bit DLL.

Comment: A 32-bit app **can** use a 64-bit out-of-proc COM object, and vice versa. Since the object has to be marshalled across process boundaries anyway, COM transparently handles any bit differences for you.